# Disabling servertokens via .htaccess breaks website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I've added the following code to my .htaccess file in my website's root folder:

```
# Disable server signature
ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerSignature Off
# END SCCC
```

It causes my website to crash:

```
Internal Server Error:
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was 
unable to complete your request.
```

Removing the `servertokens` line, it works as expected and removes the signature.

How should I be disabling servertokens? Do I even need to if I'm disabling the signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ServerTokens` only in the server config (httpd.conf):
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#servertokens

It's ok in `.htaccess` for `ServerSignature`